# Bind the 'style' property of a DropDownList inside an asp.net ListView

Tags: asp.net, .net, listview, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I have following code inside my ListView template.

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="myDropDown" Width="60px"
     SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SelectedValue") %>' 
     DataSource='<%# Eval("DropDownList") %>'
     style='display:<%# (bool)Eval("ShowDropDown") ? "block" : "none" %>;' >
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

The idea is that it will generate the html, but hidden so I can show the client-side.

However, the html generated looks like this:

```
<select id="myDropDown" 
   style="width:60px;display:<%# (bool)Eval("ShowDropDown") ? "block" : "none" %>;">
```

I don't understand why it does this. Is there a way to do this (without using classes)?

Comment: *Is* there a way to make syntax like you have work? I'm trying to do the same thing and I'd like to use syntax like that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a ListView ItemDataBound Event and then add the style attribute for dropdownlist in each row. Sample Code:

```
protected void ListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
                DropDownList myDropDown = (DropDownLiast)e.Item.FindControl("myDropDown");

                System.Data.DataRowView rowView = e.Item.DataItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
                myDropDown.Style["display"] = ((bool)rowView["ShowDropDown"])?"block":"none";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking and implementing the same thing. Only, you can also access the DataItem by casting the e.Item to a ListViewDataItem. var dataObject = ((ListViewDataItem)e.Item).DataItem as MyCustomObject;

Comment: Is it possible to use syntax like the OP has in his post? I'm trying to do the same thing.