# Dynamically adding HTML from <%: ... %> to an image where I'm modifying its parent from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to do something somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525190/bind-the-style-property-of-a-dropdownlist-inside-an-asp-net-listview). The answer there suggested doing databinding from code-behind, but I have numerous items I'm applying this to and I'd rather not do that if possible.

I have a User Control. A number of images will either be shown or hidden depending on the value of an attribute on the Custom Control. I've tried several different ways of using the `<%: ... %>` syntax to achieve this but all of them have failed for reasons I'll describe below.

My first try was to do something like the OP on the linked question. From his question:

```
<select id="myDropDown" 
        style="width:60px;display:<%# (bool)Eval("ShowDropDown") ? "block" : "none" %>;">
```

I tried something similar, but like the OP there this didn't replace `<%# (bool)Eval("ShowDropDown") ? "block" : "none" %>` with a value - it just rendered that as literal text.

The next thing I've tried (and I've tried several variants on this, none of which worked) is the following:

```
<td id="tdR1Day1" style="vertical-align: top;" runat="server">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 15px">
                <img title="Click to add pattern" <%: IsHidden ? "hidden = \"hidden\"" : "" %> align="right" id="imgR1Day1" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Add" src="../Images/Add.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
```

However, this resulted in `The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)` because I'm trying to dynamically add a `div` to the `td` tag from code behind. I'm not directly modifying the `img` itself, *just* the `td`.

When I do the exact same thing on an image that I'm *not* modifying from code-behind, I get the following HTML, which works exactly how I expect:

```
<td id="MainContent_scorpio_tdR1Day3" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 15px">
                <img hidden = &quot;hidden&quot; title="Click to add pattern" align="right" id="imgR1Day3" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Add" src="../Images/Add.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
```

My questions, then:

- When I tried doing this as part of CSS, why did it render it as literal text instead of replacing `<%: ... %>` with a value?
- Is there a way around the `The Controls collection cannot be modified...` exception?

Alternatively, am I just flat-out taking the wrong approach here? For example, should I try to just add this div/image from code-behind like I do with the other `div` in the `td`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple issues.  `<%# ... %>` is for data binding to a server control.  Your `<select>` is not a server control.  Use `<%= ... %>` which is for a display expression and just call a function.  See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp.net-inline-expressions-in-the-.net-framework) for more on inline expressions.

Assuming `IsHidden` is a boolean variable you can do this:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected string Display()
    {
        if (IsHidden) {
            return "hidden";
        }
        return "show";
    }
</script>

<select id="myDropDown" style='display:<%= Display  %>'>
    <option>
        Test
    </option>
</select>
```

I would also suggest just using a CSS class as well for that.  So something like more like

```
<style>
    .hidden {display:none;}
    .show {display:block;}
</style>

<script runat="server">
    protected string Display()
    {
        if (IsHidden) {
            return "hidden";
        }
        return "show";
    }
</script>

<select id="myDropDown" class="<%= Display %>">
    <option>
        Test
    </option>
</select>
```

*But* if you want to modify your table row in the code behind then you should indeed use the data binding inline expression e.g. `<%# ... %>` and still do the rest the same.  This will solve your `Controls collection` exception.